# Max Aggregation with Hazelcast-jet

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I want to do a simple max across an entire dataset.  I started with the Kafka example at: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/0.7-maintenance/kafka/src/main/java/avro/KafkaAvroSource.java

I just changed the pipeline to:

```
p.drawFrom(KafkaSources.<Integer, User>kafka(brokerProperties(), TOPIC))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .rollingAggregate(minBy(comparingInt(user -> (Integer) user.get(2))))
    .map(user -> (Integer) user.get(2))
    .drainTo(Sinks.list("result"));
```

and the go to:

```
IListJet<Integer> res = jet.getList("result");
SECONDS.sleep(10);
System.out.println(res.get(0));
SECONDS.sleep(15);
System.out.println(res.get(0));
cancel(job);
```

to get the largest age of people in the topic.  It however doesn't return 20 and seems to return different values on different runs.  Any idea why?

Comment: You use Kafka, which is a streaming source, but you want the result for "the entire dataset". These two seem to be at odds with each other. a Kafka source never completes so you never get the final result, just the result so far.

Comment: You're using a list sink so that each update will append to the end of the list. The value at index 0 will not change. Instead you should use a map sink with a fixed key so that the newer results overwrites the previous.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using `rollingAggregate`, which produces a new output item every time it receives some input, but all you check is the first item it emitted. You must instead find the *latest* item it emitted. One way to achieve it is by pushing the result into an `IMap` sink, using the same key every time:

```
p.drawFrom(KafkaSources.<Integer, User>kafka(brokerProperties(), TOPIC))
 .withoutTimestamps()
 .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
 .rollingAggregate(minBy(comparingInt(user -> (Integer) user.get(2))))
 .map(user -> entry("user", (Integer) user.get(2)))
 .drainTo(Sinks.map("result"));
```

You can fetch the latest result with

```
IMap<String, Integer> result = jet.getMap("result");
System.out.println(result.get("user");
```